# App not compatible with Nexus 7 and Acer Iconia a210

Tags: android, google-play

I know this has been asked a few times but why is my app not compatible with the Nexus 7 and Acer Iconia a210?

I didn't find a working solution in the existing questions so what else could I be missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="org.mw88.witness.lite"
  android:versionCode="5"
  android:versionName="2.0">

<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="14" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" 
/>

...

<supports-screens android:resizeable="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not compatible", is your app crashing or layouts are not proper?

Comment: Do not write `android:required="false"` in `<uses-permission>` It does not have that attribute. See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html).

Comment: @Jaguar: I mean it doesn't show in the Play Store

Comment: @RKN: Well, I didn't know this. Does this mean I should remove the camera permission and only use the feature?

Comment: Nope. Remove the attribute from `<uses-permission>` field. It'll not work. Check the link I given above,especially the right box text of *Google Play Filtering*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may be with the `<supports-screen>` tag in the Manifest.

Read the descriptions for the attributes in  tag [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#large) especially the screen supporting attributes.  For those attributes like [`android:smallscreens`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#small),[`android:normalscreens`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#normal) the default value is **true** as expected.

But for attributes like [`android:largescreens`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#large) and [`android:xlargescreens`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#xlarge), the default values varies.

> The default value for this actually varies between some versions, so
>   it's better if you explicitly declare this attribute at all times.

As your specified devices are tablets having large screens, stating `<support-screen>` tag may trigger in as not compatible for your app in these devices.

So either you give all the necessary attribues or remove the `<support-screens>` tag. It is not a required field to be given.

**Note:**

- If you are giving `<support-screen>` tag, remove the
  [`android:resizable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#resizeable) attribute. Its deprecated.
- Remove the `android:required="false"` from `<uses-permission>`. It'll
  not work.

Comment: Ok, the Problem could be solved by using the correct <supports-screen> properties and by adding this feature tag: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>