# Incompatible Devices with my newly released app, why?

Tags: android, google-play, compatibility, android-permissions

I have recently released an app on the Google Play Store and have received a support email from a customer wanting to download the app. However neither of his devices are compatible with the app. I've tried multiple things and I'm not really sure why it still isn't compatible. I've added "required:false" to hardware features like the camera etc. The devices he owns are the Motorola Droid Razr Maxx on 4.1.2 and the Asus Transformer TF700T on 4.2. The app's target SDK is 4.2 and therefore I'm really struggling to get these apps to work for him.  Has anybody had similar issues with any of these devices or similar? Please help me.

Here is the permissions and features from my Android Manifest, if that helps anybody:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />    
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vibrate" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: whats the minimum api level your app supports??

Comment: The minimum API level is set at 8.

Comment: please post your uses-permission & uses-feature tags from your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Sure thing. I've edited the question to add it. Please take a look.

Comment: one silly question,does your customer country supports paid apps?? as you have com.android.vending.BILLING permission..

Comment: Yeah, I know people who've already bought some of the in-app purchases fine. Good idea though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the user was from a country I wasn't currently supporting. I thought it was a given that he was also from the United Kingdom but this was not true. Please ensure that you check this before experimenting into other areas of compatibility with devices!

Answer (score 0):

please check meanifeast support screen tag as per below SO question

1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/16395758/942224

2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/17268138/942224

3) https://stackoverflow.com/a/15825934/942224

please check support screen,telephony and front camera  permission

if you don't need to capture image in surfaceview or any other view than remove camera permission.

Comment: Thanks but I have already included both support screens and camera permissions, both back and front. I had to do these due to owning a Nexus 7. These still didn't fix his problem apparently.

Comment: I've updated the question with my features and permissions from my Android Manifest. Please could you take a look to see if you could find anything obvious? Thanks.

Comment: Why should I remove it if I don't use a SurfaceView?

Comment: if you capture image using default camera than there is no need to add this permission.